# Lookup DNS using JavaScript and find IPs of particular domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in javascript. What I'm trying to do this :

```
<head>
    <title>DNS Check</title>
    <script language="javascript" src="dnscheck.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="0%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">DOMAIN:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" id="domainTxt" name="domainTxt">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="dnsCheck('domainTxt')">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

dnscheck.js file:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/home/dns.js" type="text/javascript">
    // dns.js is file downloaded from  node.js 

    function dnsCheck(domainTxt) {
        var dns = require('dns'); // syntax error 

        dns.resolve4('www.google.com', function(err, addresses) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));

            addresses.forEach(function(a) {
                dns.reverse(a, function(err, domains) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }

                    console.log('reverse for ' + a + ': ' + JSON.stringify(domains));
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

But I get a syntax error at `var dns = require('dns');`

Comment: By default, a browser doesn't have `require()`.  If you want that syntax, you will have to include a script that adds that capability.  You also can't use all `node.js` modeules in a web page.  Some will only work in node.

Comment: For urgent help call 911 or local emergency number. Otherwise find AMD framework you trying to use (maybe http://www.requirejs.org/ ) and make sure to add script reference. But as @jfriend00 pointed out it is unlikely for dns module to work in browser.